# AWS lambda nodejs runtime: io: read/write on closed pipe

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli

I am trying to execute a couple of async requests from a `lambda` function. The first call `resolveEndpoints()` succeeds and the second fails with

```
2017/11/03 17:13:27 Function oauth.callbackHandler timed out after 3 seconds

2017/11/03 17:13:27 Error invoking nodejs6.10 runtime: io: read/write on closed pipe
```

The handler is:

```
exports.callbackHandler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

    let endpoints: any = await resolveEnpoints();

    config.accessTokenUri = endpoints.token_endpoint;

    let tokenRequestPath =
    `http://localhost:7001${event.path}?code=${event.queryStringParameters.code}&realmId=${event.queryStringParameters.realmId}&`;

    let accessToken: any = await getAuthToken(tokenRequestPath);

    callback(undefined, {statusCode: 200, body: JSON.stringify(accessToken.data)});
};
```

If I remove the `resolveEndpoint()` call then `getAuthToken()` succeeds.

`resolveEndpoint()` returns a promise that resolves once the request has completed.

```
const resolveEnpoints = async () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request({
            url: config.sandboxEndpoint,
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        }, (err, response) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }

            let payload = JSON.parse(response.body);
            resolve(payload);
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: what this `resolveEnpoints()` is actually doing. And also this mayn't be a lambda related.

Comment: @VaisakhPS updated the question. As you pointed out, it could very well be lambda related but it is at the very least is a strange behaviour.

Comment: `async/await` is not supported in NodeJS 6.10. Are you sure that's the code that is running and not a compiled version?

Comment: Failed mention that it is transpiled with typescript. The code does run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lambda's default timeout is 3 seconds and I was hitting that beyond a single HTTP call. Just need to update SAM Template to increase the timeout for handlers that needs to call multiple third party services.

Updated template with timeout set to 10 seconds allows the handler to run to completion.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion : '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Description: |
  Data service

Resources:
  OAuthCallback:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Runtime: nodejs6.10
      CodeUri: ./build/services/quickbooks
      Handler: oauth2.callbackHandler
      Timeout: 10
      Events:
        AuthRoute:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /oauth2/callback
            Method: get
```